# Tracking whether user is logged-in in a stateless web application?

Tags: java, session, session-state, stateless

If I wanted to enable users to log in and out, what would be some good patterns of doing this in a stateless application?

Also, what are the top security concerns?  I am thinking of doing this in Java.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Well i thought the word "stateless" means that no state is being saved and thus no tracking of a certain user would be possible.

Comment: @ITroubs My understanding is that you would just store things in db or cookie, or some smarter way.  But I wasn't sure so I asked :)

Comment: well actually if you use JavaEE and make a JAVAEE Webapplication then there are some possible ways of declaring your beans. Statles, Session, and some other. The stateless have no possebility to identify the user. The session beans are being stored fore a certain session by the server. best about that is that the server does it automatically and you don't have to worry about handling and storing the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot store session data in user's browser (via cookie), this is probably very hard to achieve.

I'm not sure what you mean by "stateless" but if storing session key in user's browser is not possible, you can always send this "key" in the HTML you produce. This "key" will be something you randomly generate (random enough that nobody can easily guess it). The "key" is only known by you and the user. Whenever the user requests a new page, he needs to "POST" or "GET" this key as HTTP parameter if the user wants to be identified as logged in.

Security concern for this is that if you do this over non-secure (http), the network can easily be sniffed. If you do it over SSL (https) it is probably more secure.

Comment: I guess I assumed it was for a website. Similar concept applies for any other application though.

Comment: applicationdeveloper have to handle persistency. but if you are developoing a webapplication it is mostly done with JavaEE and a web app server where session generation and session handling is mostly done by the server itself so the developer doesn't have to worry about that.